# Redirecting all url's containing

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect multiple url's, but i cannot achieve / find exactly how to do it.

Basically what i need it to redirect all the pages that has in link ?page=test and ignores something=else

> www.servername.com/en/?page=test&something=else

to

> www.servername.com/en/redirected

here is what i tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^page=test\(\.\*\)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ www.servername.com/en/redirected? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Why escape the `(.*)` in `^page=test\(\.\*\)$`?

Comment: Ops forgot to remove that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex in `RewriteCond` seems to be a problem, you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=actor(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/redirected? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Also you mention `/en/` in your question and use `/index.php` in your example.

Comment: The redirect is still not firing, well basically the old link does not necessarily include /en/ but the new link does have multiple languages

Comment: What URL do you see in your browser that is supposed to redirect and didn't redirect? Also make sure this is your very first rule.

Comment: /index.php?page=actor&idactor=142
This is how it looks but i only need to redirect all pages that containt ?page=actor

Comment: But that won't redirect since it redirects only URLs with query string containing `page=test`